# Access to _vti_bin/sharedaccess.asmx Throttles SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

We have SharePoint 2013 Service Pack1 May 2015 CU. 
Of lately we see lots of  POST requests to SharePoint for end point **" _vti_bin/sharedaccess.asmx" .**

These requests just wait in IIS pipeline for as long as 3+ hours and after.
Once IIS can't take more requests, SharePoint Throttles and no one can access anything.

Any idea why this web service is hanging? What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

turns out this was a problem with Distributed Cache. The App Fabric service on the WFE stopped.  Upon restarting the service and doing an issreset , everything seems ok.

NOTE: 
In case App fabrci keeps stopping you might have to remove the cache host and add it again